# Resize image on a webpage

Tags: css

I'm working on a webpage for my HTML class and I'm having some trouble resizing an image. I'm using the code as shown below. The width attribute does not change anything.

```
   #BicycleBanner {
  margin-top: -20% ;
  height: 200%;
  width: 900%;
   }
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Please post you HTML to test, but in theory you can resize a background image in a container using the `background-size` css property.

More info here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Background_and_Borders/Scaling_background_images

Answer (score -1):

```
#BicycleBanner {
display: block;
margin-top: -20% ;
max-width:900%;
max-height:200%;
width: auto;
height: auto;
}
```